# Error: graph.open_browser() in py2neo

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

graph.open_browser()

## open well a web page, http://localhost:7474/browser/ , but no content ???

## a CYPHER request as  "MATCH (n) RETURN n ", remains necessary in order to see something

## ERROR: (process:13981): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed

Context:
Linux-Kubuntu, 
Firefox
neo4j-community-2.2.3
py2neo-2.0.7

Comment: yes neo4j doesn't display data by default, you have to run a query like in any other db too :)

Comment: ( 1 ) Glib CRITICAL ERROR: no exmplanation but the problem disapear when setting the default browser to Chromium.

Comment: ( 2 ) Our projet require a really interactive graph display.  Do you see any other graph presentation tools providing interactivity ? maybe based on popoto.js and org.neo4j.server.thirdparty_jaxrs_classes=extension.web=/popoto ?